# Chr(34) returning two double quotes characters instead of one

Tags: string, vb.net, winforms

Using Windows 10 / Visual Studio 2017 / VB.Net Win Forms application.

For some reason Chr(34) is returning "" instead of ".

Other characters seems to work just fine. Here is my immediate window output:

```
?Chr(34)
""""c
?Chr(39)
"'"c
```

Comment: The quote is escaped by doubling it up to "", other languages use the escape character \ so their equivalent is \". The character is still a single quote character.

Comment: Why are you using `Chr(34)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [Chr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a value of type `Char`, it always contains *exactly one* character, no more, no less.

What you see is an artefact of the immediate window.

The immediate window shows your char as a VB char literal, i.e. "quoted", and, thus, needs to escape double quotes (by doubling them). Use the `,nq` modifier to view unquoted strings and chars in the immediate window:

```
? Chr(34)
""""c
? Chr(34),nq
"
```

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes have to be escaped in that way.  Try sending Chr(34) to a messagebox.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it is because it is being escaped (showing the two " characters you're seeing).

For building strings in this fashion (depending on your requirements), it's best to use a StringBuilder class instead of adding quotes yourself into a String variable.

```
Dim sb as new StringBuilder

sb.AppendLine("A single double quote (" + Chr(34) + ") is shown inside a string")

System.diagnostics.debug.print(sb.ToString())
```

Output window:

A single double quote (") is shown inside a string